# Access a viewController struct from appDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a struct defined in my ViewController as follows:

```
struct Meme {
var topText : String
var bottomText : String
var originalImage : UIImage
var memedImage: UIImage
}
```

Now when I try to access the struct from appDelegate using the following code, I get an unresolved identifier error:

```
var memes = [Meme]()
```

can someone please explain why this is happening and how can i access the viewController struct from my appDelegate?

Thanks!

Comment: Show more code in order to see the context.

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: This is for a Udacity project and I am having the exact same issue. Please update when you find a solution and I will do the same. It appears that the app delegate does not recognize the Struct Meme. Unfortunately we must use this struct in the appDelegate as a shared model per the instructions of the course so work arounds will not solve this.

Comment: I actually figured this out long back. Sorry for the delay in update. People with the same problem, please create a new swift file called "Meme.swift" and then write the meme struct inside that file. Your problem should be solved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the properties of a class without having an instance of it.

In `AppDeletegate` file do this:

```
  // create instance of your viewcontroller class
  let viewController = ViewController() 
  // access the property
  viewController.memes = [Meme]()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in another way to:

```
import UIKit

var memes = [Meme]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

ok the memes are not exacly in the scope of UIViewController, but they are in the same file, like this they are global variable.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        print(memes[0].bottomText)

        return true
    }
```

Wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the struct is defined inside your ViewController class like you said, you will need to access it using the namespace of the ViewController in the following way:

```
var memes = [MyViewController.Meme]()
```

Comment: This solution results in another error "Cannot call value of non-function type '[MemeViewController.Meme.Type]'. X-Code suggests this can be fixed by deleting "()" but this only results in more errors.

Comment: Well it would be `[MemeViewController.Meme]()`. No need to put `.Type`.

Comment: I'd make sure then that your struct is declared at the top level (not inside any classes). Then you should be able to use it as the course describes.

Comment: The issue was the example had it written inside the class! Thank you so much. It can be written the way the OP has it shown, but it needs to be above/outside the view class.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out long back. Sorry for the delay in update. People with the same problem, please create a new swift file called "Meme.swift" and then write the meme struct inside that file. Your problem should be solved now. Thanks!